# How to add a C# custom rule to SonarQube using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, roslyn

I wrote a C# Roslyn analyzer. It works ok and detects the issue as expected.

Nevertheless, when I try to deploy it under SonarQube using the Roslyn-SDK like this:

```
RoslynSonarQubePluginGenerator /a:SleepRule
```

I get that error:

```
Attempting to locate package with id 'SleepRule'
[DEBUG] Number of packages located: 0
No packages with the specified id were found: SleepRule
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Roslyn 4.6.86 to generate the Nuget package of the analyzer using Roslyn, and I want to add the rule to Sonarqube 6.3.

Comment: Can you please show the line that generates the DiagnosticDescriptor incl. the arguments used for the constructor? Thanks.

Comment: sure, here it is: 
        private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

Comment: It looks like the generator can't find your package. I checked, and it's not on nuget.org. Did you specify your nuget feed in the config file? See here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-roslyn-sdk#configuring-nuget-feeds?

Comment: Thanks, now it's working, what made me do it wrong was that I added before a FirstAnalyzerCs normally, now I see it's already in nuget.org
If you want, you can change your answer in a new one and not in a comment, so I mark it as a solution